# Knockout visible: $index not working

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have a grid where I want the first row to not display.  I have the following tag to accomplish this:

```
<div data-bind="visible: $index">....</div>
```

Unfortunately, I'm not seeing style="display: none;" showing up in the tag and sure enough, the div is displaying.

By the way, I had also tried this and it didn't work either:

```
<div data-bind="style: { display: $index ? 'block' : 'none' }">....</div>
```

I must be missing something very simple.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the complete grid html code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$index` is an observable so right now your binding is just checking if the function isn't undefined or null which results in a true ... thus you always see the first row. Change your binding to this:

```
<div data-bind="visible: $index() > 0">....</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I could have sworn that I read in the Knockout documentation that visible was able to process the commands differently and that I didn't have to specify the function.  The following is what I ended up using
`style: { display: $index() > 0 ? 'block' : 'none' }`

Comment: @MikeHomol You have to specify the parenthesis when you need to return and examine the value stored in your observable as part of some expression such as a boolean expression in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like the issue was a separate script that was setting an opacity of 1 for one of the classes being set in this div.  So I had to add the class to the data-bind as well.